# Future of Farm Solutions for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sandbox-solution, farm-solution

As per the new MS article about phasing out of SandBox solution and moving on to APP only solution, what is the future of Farm solution.

As per the below article -

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721992(v=office.14).aspx

Farm solutions are deployed on front-end Web servers by a farm administrator, have full access to the server object model, and are not subject to any usage limits. By comparison, sandboxed solutions can be deployed by a site collection administrator — or by a user who has the Full Control permission level at the root of the site collection.

Farm Solution is different from SandBox solution.

As per the below article SandBox support will be phased.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff607742.aspx
There is no clarity about the future of Farm Solutions, will the support of Farm Solution will be phased out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I have information, I doubt anything will change with respect to farm solutions. They exist since the first version of SharePoint and are the most powerful way to develop solutions in SharePoint. Among other things:

- Better performance
- Code more "ordered"
- Compiled code
- Simpler to use
- Elevated privileges
- More classes

It does not seem that this model can disappear. Although it is my opinion. But if the needs of a project require a farm solution, I would not stop opting for this approach today (2016),